# Race condition with synchronized() blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, race-condition, synchronized

```
package server.Bank;

import server.Bank.Exceptions.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class
Bank {

    private final ArrayList<Account> accounts;//lista di account
    private final ArrayList<Account> transfer_i;//lista di account che stanno effettuando sessione interattive

    /* Costruttore della classe */
    public Bank() {
        accounts = new ArrayList<>();
        transfer_i = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /* Metodo di apertura del conto */
    public void open(String name, Double amount) throws AccountAlreadyExists, InvalidAmountException {
        synchronized (accounts) {
            if (existsAccount(name)) {
                throw new AccountAlreadyExists("The account already exists");
            } else if (invalidAmount(amount)) {
                throw new InvalidAmountException("You can't open an account with a negative amount");
            }
            int ID = accounts.size();
            accounts.add(new Account(name, amount, ID));
        }
    }

    private boolean existsAccount(String name) {
        for (Account a : accounts) {
            if (a.getName().equals(name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean invalidAmount(Double amount) {
        return amount < 0;
    }

    /* Restituisce un account in base al nome */
    public Account getAccount(String name) throws AccountNotExists {
        if (name == null) {             //eccezione se parametro == null (prima eccezione)
            throw new AccountNotExists("Name cannot be null");
        }
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (account.getName().equals(name)) {
                return account;
            }
        }                               //eccezione se nome non presente (seconda eccezione)
        throw new AccountNotExists("Account with given name not found");
    }

    /* Comando list del client */
    public String list() {
        String s = "";
        if (accounts.size() == 0) {
            s = "No account has been registered yet";
        } else {
            for (Account a : accounts) {
                s += a.toString() + "\n\n";
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    public void transfer(String acc1, String acc2, double amount) throws InvalidAmountException,
      AccountNotExists, AccountNotAvailable, SafeIllegalArgumentException {
        //controllare se amount sia corretto, altrimenti errore, se ne occupa ConnectionHandler con IOException()
        if (acc1.equals(acc2)) {
            throw new SafeIllegalArgumentException("You can't transfer money to yourself");
        }
        //devo verificare che il conto non sia nella lista transfer_i;
        Account g1 = getAccount(acc1);
        Account g2 = getAccount(acc2);
        //se gli account non esistono viene lanciata l'eccezione AccountNotExists gestito dal getAccount():
        while (isTransfer_i(g1) || isTransfer_i(g2)) {
            synchronized(this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                    //aspetta che entrambi i conti NON siano presenti nella lista
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Thread interrupted");
                }
            }
        }
        //race condition here
        transaction(g1, g2, amount);
    }

    /* Effettivo trasferimento dei soldi da un conto all'altro */
    private void transaction(Account acc1, Account acc2, double amount) throws InvalidAmountException {
        //verifica che l'amount sia valido
        if (acc1.getBalance() < amount) {
            throw new InvalidAmountException("Not enough money in sender account");
        }

        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new InvalidAmountException("Amount must be positive");
        }
        Account[] accounts = orderAccounts(acc1,acc2);
        synchronized (accounts[0]) {
            synchronized (accounts[1]) {
                //effettua trasferimento da un conto all'altro
                try {
                    if (accounts[0].getName().equals("Account1")) {
                        Thread.sleep(6000);
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){}

                acc1.setLastTransaction(new Transaction(-amount, acc1, acc2));
                acc1.updateBalance(-amount);
                acc2.setLastTransaction(new Transaction(amount, acc1, acc2));
                acc2.updateBalance(amount);
            }
        }
    }


    private Account[] orderAccounts(Account acc1, Account acc2){
        Account[] order = new Account[2];
        if (acc1.getID() < acc2.getID()) {
            order[0] = acc1;
            order[1] = acc2;
        } else {
            order[0] = acc2;
            order[1] = acc1;
        }
        return order;
    }

    /* Avvio di una sessione interattiva */
    public void transfer_iInitiate(String acc1, String acc2) throws AccountNotExists, AccountNotAvailable, SafeIllegalArgumentException {
        if (acc1.equals(acc2)) {
            throw new SafeIllegalArgumentException("You can't transfer money to yourself");
        }
        Account g1 = getAccount(acc1);
        Account g2 = getAccount(acc2);

        while (getAccountTransfer_i(acc1) != null || getAccountTransfer_i(acc2) != null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Thread interrupted");
                }
            }
        }
        //race condition here
        Account[] accounts = orderAccounts(g1,g2);
        synchronized (accounts[0]) {
            synchronized (accounts[1]) {
                transfer_i.add(g1);
                transfer_i.add(g2);
            }
        }

    }

    public void move(String acc1, String acc2, double amount) throws InvalidAmountException, AccountNotExists, AccountNotAvailable, SafeIllegalArgumentException {
        Account g1 = getAccount(acc1);
        Account g2 = getAccount(acc2);
        transaction(g1, g2, amount);
    }

    /* Termina la sessione interattiva */
    public void transfer_iEnd(String acc1, String acc2) throws AccountNotExists {
        Account g1 = getAccount(acc1);
        Account g2 = getAccount(acc2);
        Account[] accounts = orderAccounts(g1,g2);
        synchronized (accounts[0]) {
            synchronized (accounts[1]) {
                transfer_i.remove(g2);
            }
            transfer_i.remove(g1);
        }
        synchronized(this) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public Account getAccountTransfer_i(String name) {
        Account res = null;
        for (Account account : transfer_i) {
            if (account.getName().equals(name)) {
                res = account;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public boolean isTransfer_i(Account name) {
        return transfer_i.contains(name);
        //true se contiene il conto
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do a simple bank-project with multithreading. The two main operations are transfer and transfer_i (means an interactive session to transfer money from an account to the other).
I have two race condition problems, in method transfer_iInitiate, and transfer (look for `//race condition` comment).
Transfer_iInitiate memorises the accounts involved in an interactive session inside of the ArrayList transfer_i. How to avoid this race condition, without using synchronized in the method signature or without using synchronized(this)? As the aim is to simultaneously do a transfer_i from a to b and a transfer_i from c to d (in two different threads). (where a, b, c and d are the name of different Accounts)

I tried to use:

```
syncrhonized(acc1){
  synchronized(acc2){
  ....
  }
}
```

where inside of the synchronized block i put either the while and the operations transfer_i.add(...). Unfortunately I realized that I cannot call wait on two objects in a row inside of the while (on acc1 e acc2), and I can't think of a different solution, any suggestion?

Comment: One thing you could do is to add a single 'transaction complete' object which is the object that is waited on.  And every transaction completion notifies that object, so all waiters wake up and recheck for completion of their particular transaction.  That seems a bit hokey to me, but I don't see any simple way to fix this.

Comment: Create new table which holds all accounts and their active transactions. Then, if you try to make transfer between accounts check if users in this table have active transactions. If they have then sleep your thread, else process transfer.

Comment: One way this is solved in the real world is to use an optimistic lock.  Especially for long held locks (your interactive session) optimistic locks are preferred.  Optimistic locks do not work well if there is contention (lots of changes) so you do have to be careful of that situation.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run multiple transactions in parallel you could consider this possible solution

First some sort of java objects to deal with the concurrency of the application.

```
    private final Set<Integer> accountsInUse = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    private final Set<Future<TransactionResult>> transactions = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock reader = lock.readLock();
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock writer = lock.writeLock();

    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    private final Timer transactionChecker = new Timer();
```

accountsInUse is basically  to know what accounts are beign used at the moment.  Reentrant objects are to protect accountsInUse to be written or read when another thread is accessing it.

The executor is to run your transactions in separately and transactions is to know if they already finish or not.

Now you need a callable class to do your operations

```
static class TransactionThread implements Callable<TransactionResult> {

    Account acc1;
    Account acc2;
    double amount;

    TransactionThread(Account acc1, Account acc2, double amount) {
        this.acc1 = acc1;
        this.acc2 = acc2;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public TransactionResult call() throws Exception {
        if (acc1.getBalance() < amount) {
            throw new InvalidAmountException("Not enough money in sender account");
        }

        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new InvalidAmountException("Amount must be positive");
        }
        Account[] accounts = orderAccounts(acc1, acc2);

        acc1.setLastTransaction(new Transaction(-amount, acc1, acc2));
        acc1.updateBalance(-amount);
        acc2.setLastTransaction(new Transaction(amount, acc1, acc2));
        acc2.updateBalance(amount);

        return new TransactionResult("SUCCESS", acc1.getID(), acc2.getID());
    }
}
record TransactionResult(String status, int acc1Id, int acc2Id) {
}
```

Then you need to update the method to run your transactions

```
public void transfer(String acc1, String acc2, double amount) throws InvalidAmountException,
            AccountNotExists, AccountNotAvailable, SafeIllegalArgumentException {
        //controllare se amount sia corretto, altrimenti errore, se ne occupa ConnectionHandler con IOException()
        writer.lock();
        if (acc1.equals(acc2)) {
            writer.unlock();
            throw new SafeIllegalArgumentException("You can't transfer money to yourself");
        }
        //devo verificare che il conto non sia nella lista transfer_i;
        Account g1 = getAccount(acc1);
        Account g2 = getAccount(acc2);
        reader.lock();
    if(accountsInUse.contains(g1.getID()) || accountsInUse.contains(g2.getID())) {
        writer.unlock();
        throw new SafeIllegalArgumentException("Accounts in Use");
    }
    reader.unlock();
    writer.lock();
    accountsInUse.add(g1.getID());
    accountsInUse.add(g2.getID());
    //se gli account non esistono viene lanciata l'eccezione AccountNotExists gestito dal getAccount():
    transactions.add(executor.submit(new TransactionThread(g1, g2, amount)));
    writer.unlock();
    }
```

Here you use the WriteLock and ReadLock to prevent other thread to write/read in your accsountsInUse Set while is not allowed.

Note that every thread you execute with the Executor return a Future, That object will tell you if the process is over or not.

So finally, you need something to check for the Future list of objects (transactions). A timer can help on this.

So in your constructor:

```
public Bank() {
        accounts = new ArrayList<>();
        transfer_i = new ArrayList<>();
        TimerTask taskChecker = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                reader.lock();
                List<Integer> finishedTransactions = transactions.stream()
                        .filter(Future::isDone).map(f->{
                            try {
                                return f.get();
                            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        })
                        .flatMap(tr -> Stream.of(tr.acc1Id(), tr.acc2Id()))
                        .toList();
                accountsInUse.stream().filter(finishedTransactions::contains).toList().forEach(accountsInUse::remove);
                reader.unlock();
            }
        };
        transactionChecker.schedule(taskChecker, 0, 1000);
    }
```

This is just a simple timer that will be checking for all finished transactions  and remove them from the accountsInUse Set if they are done..

There are lots of improvements that can be made here but I just did a quick sample on how you can handle this. Hope this helps.